# Interpret radare2 help

Tags: radare2

So I run radare2 from the command line with `r2 -` and attempt to display the help with the `?` command. I read this line which says:

`?[??][expr]             Help or evaluate math expression`

I am not sure how to read this. I assume the first `?` is `Help` command. And the rest `[??][expr]` is evaluate math expression. However, something like this `?? 0xa` does not return anything. So, my question is how to correctly interpret this output from the help.

Comment: `?` is indeed Help. To evaluate expression you need `??? expr`.

Comment: Have you tried `> ? 0x32`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me some time to realize that the 2 helps were kind of combined into one.

The first question mark symbol can mean either help or evaluate math expression. The second and third are optional if used in the context of evaluating an expression.